# Training xgboost model with more data having different characteristic

Tags: python, classification, predictive-modeling, decision-trees, xgboost

I have trained my model for ECG data which has 8528 ECG files having length `30s` and sample rate `300` so total file length in csv is `9000`. Data has four classes i.e. `A`, `N`,`O` and `~`

This model is working fine.

Now I want to retrain the model using few more ecg files. Which has length `42s` and sample rate `360`. So total csv file of this ecg signal has length `15127`.

I trained model with `A` file having length `15127`, then I tried to predict same file with trained model, but it predicts class value `N`.

Can anyone visualie how Xgboost will learn with added such file having signal length more? Does such file encountered as outlier?

If I train model with more `A` having lenth `15127` length will model be able to predict it correctly?

Let me know if any information required.

Here is sample training code :;

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_data,label=train_labels)
# cross_validate(dtrain)
print('training model.....')
param = {'num_class':4,'objective':'multi:softmax','eval_metric':['merror'],'max_depth':7,'eta':0.04,'subsample':0.8,'min_child_weight':0.5,'max_delta_step':7,'gamma':2,'lambda':10,'colsample_bytree':0.5}
model = xgb.train(param,dtrain,420,[(dtrain,'train')],verbose_eval=20)
print('saving model....')
model.save_model('xgb_model.bin')
print('done!')
```

Comment: So the second file has only `A`'s in it?? I haven't work with ecg, Could you share how is the training data? I guess you have 360 row and 43 variables (42 seconds + target). Am I right?

Comment: @Ismor: No you are taking it other way. You can consider ECG as a signal record. (another example of signal record is Audio signal). Which has sample rate 360 and signal is 42 second long. So that size of one file is 360*42. 

How it looks like is : csv file. Signal to converted to value and stored in csv file. I have such 8529 records(rows), each row for different signal.